# Angular Django Hello World

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I cannot use Angular inside Django. Here is my code:

angularapp.js

```
var APP = angular.module('APP', []);

    APP.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]')};

    APP.ApplicationCtrl = function ($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'World';

    };
```

angular.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="angularapp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="APP" ng-controller="APP.ApplicationCtrl">
    <h1>Hello [[ name ]]!</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Both files are in the same folder. When the project starts, the terminal shows:

```
[02/Jun/2016 17:30:35] "GET /django-sb-admin/angularapp.js HTTP/1.1" 200 297"
```

In the browser I see only:

```
Hello [[ name ]]!
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Your issue is with Angular library, there is no Django here.

Answer (score 1):

The code has a typo as you forgot to close the function brace `)`.

```
APP.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]')
};
```

Correct code:

```
APP.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');        
});
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VmSAhGiePsKUAyBXZ45G?p=preview)

Comment: Yes I forgot, Thx but still doesn't work. I see only Hello [[ name ]]!

Comment: Shouldnt there be a reference to django file in your file angular.html? Can you create a plunker to replicate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see at [verbatim](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) for change brackets in django, not in angular